# SQL Query DBMS Actually Executes When View Query Uses an Aliased Aggregate Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a 3-step homework problem and I'm stumped on the last step. For the last step to make sense, I'll post the entire problem including my solutions for the first two steps:

**The Problem and My Solutions for the First Two Steps**

Create a view named TRIP_INVENTORY. It consists of the state and the total number of trips for each state. Use UNITS as the column name for the total number of trips for each state. Group and order the rows by state.

a. Write and execute the CREATE VIEW command to create the TRIP_INVENTORY view.

```
CREATE VIEW TRIP_INVENTORY AS
SELECT STATE, COUNT(TRIP_ID) AS UNITS
FROM TOURS_TRIP
GROUP BY STATE
```

b. Write and execute the command to retreive the state and units for each state having more than 10 trips.

```
SELECT STATE, UNITS
FROM TRIP_INVENTORY
WHERE UNITS > 10
```

**The Step that has Me Stumped**

c. Write and execute the query that the DBMS actually executes.

*This was the unsuccessful query I came up with:*

```
SELECT STATE, COUNT(TRIP_ID) AS UNITS
FROM TOURS_TRIP
WHERE UNITS > 10
GROUP BY STATE
```

The problem is that the UNITS column alias can't be referenced in the WHERE clause. I can't use an aggregate function in the WHERE clause either. I'm pretty sure I need to use a subquery, but I can't figure out how to structure the constraints so that they will remove the unnecessary states using the results of the nested query.

Can anyone offer any insight?

Comment: Look up the difference between WHERE and HAVING

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the implementation but

**b)**

```
SELECT STATE, COUNT(TRIP_ID) AS UNITS
FROM TOURS_TRIP
GROUP BY STATE
having COUNT(TRIP_ID) > 10
```

**c)**

```
Select state, units from (
  SELECT STATE, COUNT(TRIP_ID) AS UNITS
  FROM TOURS_TRIP
  GROUP BY STATE
) temp (state,units) 
where units > 10
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't even aware that you could use a subquery in the FROM clause.

Answer (score 0):

should be

```
  SELECT STATE, COUNT(TRIP_ID) AS UNITS
    FROM TOURS_TRIP
    GROUP BY STATE
    having COUNT(TRIP_ID) > 10
```